# ReactApplicationContext cannot be cast to AppCompatActivity when trying to implement a SDK

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to implement a payment gateway sdk. When I initialize the sdk with ReactApplicationContext it gives me the following error.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactApplicationContext cannot be cast to androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
```

The code to initialize the sdk

```
IntegrateSSLCommerz.getInstance(reactContext).addSSLCommerzInitialization(sslCommerzInitialization).buildApiCall(new SSLCTransactionResponseListener() {
                @Override
                public void transactionSuccess(SSLCTransactionInfoModel transactionInfoModel) {
                    Log.d("SSL", "Transaction ID: " + transactionInfoModel.getTranId());
                     callBack.invoke("success");
                }

                @Override
                public void transactionFail(String s) {
                    Log.e("SSL", "Transaction ID: " + s);
                     callBack.invoke("fail");
                }

                @Override
                public void merchantValidationError(String s) {
                      callBack.invoke("error");
                }
            });

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
```

Can anyone give a solution please? I have gone trough the previous question on stack overflow but there is no clear solution for this specific problem